# How to convert float to int : android

Tags: java

```
float NormValue = value*80 ;
float color = Color.argb(0xFF, NormValue, 0, 0);
```

This is a part of my code.
This variable (NormValue) stores the result in float . But in second line i cannot use this variable since it has to be converted to int. How can i do it. Any help?

Comment: you can cast it by int by writing (int)color.

Answer (score 13):

Try this..

**No need to typecast** `float` to `int` just use `Math.round()`

```
float NormValue = value*80 ;
float color = Color.argb(0xFF, Math.round(NormValue), 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 6):

Depends on the scale of your `NormValue`.

Normally, a simple type cast would do:

```
(int)NormValue
```

But you may want to scale the `NormValue` to the range 0..255 first since `Color.argb()` just uses the least significant 8 bits of the int values passed in.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

Convert it to string

```
String.valueOf(value);
```

and then convert it to integer

```
Integer.valueOf(string);
```

You can also try casting it to int

```
Int i =  (int) your_float_value
```

Comment: Thanks all but i solved it in my own way...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
float NormValue = value*80 ;
int temp = (int)NormValue;
float color = Color.argb(0xFF, temp, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Android is java, right?
You can simply cast it to int like this.

```
float f=0.2;
int i;

i = (int)f;
```

Answer (score 0):

You really need to use float in the first place?
You have two options:
1. Use casting int normInt = (int)NormValue; but here you have to be prepared that you will loose the decimal points. eg: 8.61 will be 8
2. The second way to first round the NormValue then use casting.

Answer (score -3):

You can search in this post, your solution is there:
[Java: (int)(float)Float.valueOf(s) or Float.valueOf(s).toInt()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986034/java-intfloatfloat-valueofs-or-float-valueofs-toint)

If you want more information, you can ask me :)